# Return response from Server using JSONP

Tags: json, jquery, jquery-plugins, jsonp

[RE-EDIT]
I am trying to pass a value to the server and read from the server using JSONP. I have been able to implement this code:

```
var record = new Object();  

     record["deviceID"] = "123"; 
     options = {

          url: "http://192.168.2.143:8080/commapi/comaction/init?callback=?",

          type: "POST",

          data: {dataset: JSON.stringify(record) },
              jsonp: "callback",

          dataType: "jsonp",
              callbackParameter: "jsoncallback",

          success: function(result) {

              alert(result["retdic.deviceID"]);

          },
              error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              alert("ERROR: " + textStatus);
              alert("ERROR: " + errorThrown);
        }
           };
          jQuery.ajax(options);
```

});

However I receive an invalid label error from FireFox firebug. Could anyone please let me know what it is I am doing wrong? A few examples would be great;y appreciated.

Thanks.

[RE-EDIT]
The error produced is:

```
  invalid label
{"ret":"ACK","retdic":{"ak":"Bvr7/ljfj...X212yA+XJR5+AdrmE=","deviceID":"123"}}
```

The error returned is parseError. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Could anyone give me a hand, please?

Thanks.

Comment: try using just alert(result) or even better console.log(result) to see what you get from the page :)

Comment: Marco, there are no results returned :(

Comment: Try using Firebug/IE Developers NET tracking, to see if your json call reaches the target page, and if it gets a response back :)

Comment: Marco, I've added the error that is now produced..

Comment: Is that on the php script or on you page? Could you try using normal data like data: {deviceID : 123} instead? :)

Comment: No Marco, thanks but that did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

This could solve your problem:

[Jquery getJSON to external PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790910/jquery-getjson-to-external-php-page/790931#790931)

Just make sure your shared some server-side code, so that we know how the response should look like

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 alert(result.retdic.deviceID);
```

Comment: can you only try with this alert(JSON.stringify(result)); in your success callback. It will alert the all json data that success function has returned. also remove jsonp: "callback", and use dataType: "json", in your code.

Comment: Thanks Vikas, but I still receive the invalid label error..am at wits end now..not sure what I'm doing wrong!!